# Run Certain PHP code from $_POST?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Server 1 : Post a ***name*** variable to server 2. (e.g. "*Adam*")

Server 2 : Receives the post variable and makes a new control from it as follows which displays *Adam* as the value.

```
<input name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>" />
```

Wich renders finally :

```
<input name="name" value="Adam" />
```

Now my question is as follows, i want to pass certain PHP code in the post variable **name**, so that i am able to run it on SERVER 2.

For example `<?php echo "foo"; ?>` is passed as post variable so that server 2 render it in html.

**Is this possible?**

- If yes, how can it be done?
- If No, What is reason behind it as i know the variable being passed is being compiled by the server and php is a server side script.

Comment: first of of you can't pass a *variable* via HTTP it will every time a request (variable has a different meaning) ... to your question... it is possible but you don't want it! ... the magic keyword is eval() and *eval is evil*!

Comment: If you can tell us why you want to do this, maybe we can give you a better solution.

Comment: @donald123 if you want to use eval(), you need to modify the server 2 aswell. Right? so that we are able to handle whatever was passed from server 1. Or we can also handle that from Server 1.

Comment: @PHPhil As if now i have this requirement from the client for which am looking out ways to get it done. Curiously, i never knew this was possible. So, started trying it out.

Comment: @Harsh eval() don't need a server modification ... and I DONT WANT TO USE eval() :)

Comment: Ok Sir @donald123 No eval(), but i need get this done. eval() or whatever it takes. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to post PHP code to another page and then use the PHP function eval() to process it. (The string you are evaluating must have a return instruction to allow for any kind of response `$return = eval("return 5;")`

HOWEVER, I would not recommend it, it's very very open to malice.

Comment: so how does this eval work and why do we need to use it? As when i try to enter the code using escape characters, my HTML just automatically comments out the php code passed. I am sorry if this is a foolish question because am relatively new to php.

Comment: It's not a foolish question at all, but it's certainly not a practice that anyone here would recommend. the eval function evaluations the PHP code you supply it with, so if you were to supply a script that said "delete all files in the document root, it would, if it had permission to do so. By sending PHP code from one server to another you are opening yourself to a world of pain... Check out php.net for documentation.

Comment: But why does an html comment out my script that was passed. You did not answer this "As when i try to enter the code using escape characters, my HTML just automatically comments out the php code passed"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you aim.

If you want to display "foo" in the Server2-form, it is simple:
`<input name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>" />`
this results in html:
`<input name="name" value="Adam" />`

If you want to pass **php code**, you need to escape some chars :
`<input name="name" value="\<\?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>" />`
but it seems useless, since $_POST['name'] wont be reachable no more.
You should use `eval(/*php code*/)` but your POST variable is lost anyway.
**Anyway, passing php code is just BAD in such a way. dont do**. It is an wide opened door for hacking.
*You should improve your conception/architecture* and tell us what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: I have tried using this withoug eval() and my code is just gets commented out in the html formed. Don't know the reason though. Anyways, as per the requirement of client. This is what needs to be done even if its open to malice.

Comment: just have a doubt to your answer, so as you have given the answer. Now when the POST request happens it will look something like this `<input name="name" value="<?php echo eval(<?php echo "foo"; ?>) ?>" />` .. I doubt if this will work.

Comment: @Harsh actually,to help you, I really need to better know what is your goal in that all. Explain it very simply please. passing php code like this is dirty and dangerous. waiting for simple goal explaination & relevent details plz. /// `<input name="name" value="<?php echo eval(<?php echo "foo"; ?>) ?>" />` is absolutly madness... dont do it.

Comment: @Harsh : it is very simple, with POST you can post strings. "Adam" or php code like `mysqlconnect(/*destroy it*/)`. If Server  wants to execute the php code, just do `eval($_POST["name"]` .

Answer (score 0):

Running PHP dynamically from either POST, GET or other source is possible using [eval](http://php.net/manual/es/function.eval.php) or better yet, using [runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) virtual machine.

Please, be aware that this is a very bad practice if not designed properly, and can lead to your systems being exploited, because you are essentially giving a "free pass" for everyone to run code on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Executing remote PHP code is a **very** bad idea but the least you can do, if you choose to do it anyway, is make sure your data is safe during transport. The absolute minimum for that is using SSL to make the POST request through, lets say, [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

```
$code = '<?php echo $foo; ?>'; // Make sure you use a literal string here.
$data = array('code' => $code); 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // Read the notice bellow!
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

In order for this setup to properly protect your data and prevent stuff like MITM attacks you need to use a signed certificate. `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` will help you test the system in a developer environment but you should **NEVER** turn it off in production.

Once again, the whole remote code execution idea is pretty bad but if I had to do it this would probably be the way how I would do it.

Comment: You posted the code to the https://example.com server. But how will it get compiled on this server. This is what am not able to understand!

Comment: The main problem here is not how to execute the code on example.com but how to prevent someone from altering your PHP code while it travels from the first server to example.com. On example.com you will still need to use something like `eval` which again, is a very bad idea.

Comment: Right.. That means until and unless the second server is not executing with the help of eval(). The code will in actual never compiled. Right now am not concerned about security. Just need to know how the end to end process works.

Comment: It's not rocket science. You are just making a simple POST request, like you would normally do. In PHP you use cURL or streams for that.

Comment: Making a post request is fine But how to parse it on the second server. Like how will the following code work when pass your `$code` is sent to the second server as post variable `<input name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>" />`

Comment: Now the question moves on :P, is there a way of doing it without modifying the second server code? LIke without using eval on the second server or something like sending eval from the first server(from where we are actually making the post request). The idea is that this particular line cannot be modified `<input name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>" />`

Comment: No, there is no way to do it without modifying code on the target server.

Comment: @donald123 has mentioned in the comments, that it is possible. That is why i became a little curious as to how this is possible. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple, with POST you can post strings. "Adam" or php code like `mysqlconnect(/*destroy it*/)`. If Server  wants to execute the php code, just do a **php** `eval($_POST["name"]);`

`<?php
eval($_POST["name"]);
?>`

this is equivalent of:

`<?php
mysqlconnect(/*destroy it*/);
?>`

You can, it is possible. But you should not do it.

---

There is no other way.
Why ? Because PHP is made like that. This is it.

is Your client owning a  computer science diploma ? No,
it seems obvious.
You or the client has to reevaluate the strategy of it all.
Your client thinks he's right ? If he s god, respect God.
And play with eval(). Just tell him the risk.
It is his own choice. good luck with pretentious clients...